# Magento 2 Show selected Bundel Product Option into Popup

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, modal-popup

**I have create one custom Module. I need to get bundle product html into popup like give below. I have product id.**
[image]

> **How to achive this ?**

Comment: Can you explain in more details what is the problem?
What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i need to get  when customer click on edit open popup and show above data like above with selected option.